# SQL select rows into new columns

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a database table which looks like this:

```
ID         parameter          value
1          A                  1
1          B                  1002
2          A                  5
2          B                  1055
```

I would like to create a SQL query to receive such a table:

```
ID         value of parameter A            value of parameter B
1          1                               1002
2          5                               1055
```

How can I transform the table to create a new columns for each parameter with it corresponding value?

Comment: That's called a "pivot". Is the list/number of `parameter` fixed and known in advance?

Comment: Ah ok good to know. Yes the number of parameters is fixed (15) but some have no values (nan).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can combine `CASE` with any aggregation function (like `SUM()`, `MAX()`, etc.) to pivot the data manually.

For example:

```
select
  id,
  sum(case when parameter = 'A' then value end) as a,
  sum(case when parameter = 'B' then value end) as b,
  ...
  sum(case when parameter = 'Z' then value end) as z
from t
group by id
```

Comment: This seems to be slow when the dataset is large. Any suggestion to speed up?

Comment: You are reading the entire table to produce the result, since there's no filterting condition. It's bound to be slow. Having said that, adding an index on `(id, parameter)` may somewhat speed up the query.